# example on using google map v3+gwt through jsni

Tags: gwt, google-maps

any example on using google map v3 with gwt1.6.4 through jsni ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/

Answer (score 4):

```
native void initializeMap() /*-{
    var latlng = new $wnd.google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: $wnd.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new $wnd.google.maps.Map($doc.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}-*/;
```